# Error updating more than one Row in a Table:org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to update some rows (10) at the same time in a Table. These rows have been created with Hibernate with no problem, but when I try to update them based on the PK of the table it shows the following error:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: `More than one row with the given identifier was found:`  because there are 10 rows with that Id.

This is the persistence of the class:

```
  @javax.persistence.Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PARENT", unique = false, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
    public long getIdParent() {
        return this.idParent;
    }

    public void setIdParent (long idParent) {
        this.idParent = idParent;
    }
```

In order to update the rows I use the following code:

```
for (int i=0;i<Dto.getDescription().size();i++){
                    insertI18N.setIdParent(entity1.getCodCustomerCptType());
                    insert.setDescription(Dto.getDescription().get(i));
                    insert.setLocale(Dto.getLocale().get(i));
                    insertList.add(insertI18N);
                    gcomCustomerCptTypeI18NDao.update(insertList);
                    }
```

Kind Regards

Comment: If it is PK then how there can be 10 rows in database?

Comment: It is a Pk and I can create more than one rows with the same Id

Comment: if the field is primary key then it should be unique and not-null, it seems you just created a column without declaring it as primary key in database. You cannot use this as an identifier, hibernate won't support like that.

Comment: Primary keys are supposed to be unique. Hibernate requires that uniqueness to update data.

Comment: The thing is that I've created a lot of rows wih the same Id without problem. The PK is declared in this table.